# clicking a radio button and displaying an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I display an image in my context box, when I click a specific radio button?
How do I manipulate a certain radio button to display an image inside the scene box? The radio buttons are made from jquery and javascript, not html. Any solutions or help?

```
function initialize() {
    var initialScene = getScene("scene1");
    displayScene(initialScene);
}

function changeScene(selectedOption) {
    var selectedSceneId = selectedOption.value;
    var selectedScene = getScene(selectedSceneId);
    if (selectedScene == "scene6") {
        $("#content").effect(
            {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000,
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        $("#content").effect(
            {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 1000,
                complete: function () {
                    displayScene(selectedScene);
                    $("#content").effect("fade", 1000);
                }
            });
    }
}


function displayScene(scene) {
    $("#sceneTitle").html(scene.title);
    $("#sceneText").html(scene.text);
    $("#sceneOptions").html(createSceneOptions(scene));
}

function getScene(sceneId) {
    var matchedScenes = $.grep(scenes, function (scene) {
        return scene.id == sceneId;
    });

    return matchedScenes[0];
}

function createSceneOptions(scene) {
    var sceneOptions = "";
    $.each(scene.options, function (index, option) {
        sceneOptions += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"options\" value=\"" + option.nextSceneId + "\" id=\"" + index + "\" onclick=\"changeScene(this)\"><label for=\"" +  index   +  "\">" + option.text + "</label><br/>";
    });

    return sceneOptions;
}
```

My radio buttons consist of jquery, so my only html I have for the radio buttons is

```
<div id="sceneOptions">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCN8S/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Brannan2/QCN8S/... my external jquery codes dont seem to work on jfiddle. not sure if it will help

Comment: thanks for fixing the fiddle, tymeJV. Any help? The text is white because I had an image for the background. but thats besides the point. :)

Comment: Can anyone help? let me know. I know the simple way with onClick of a radio button, but my code doesn't consist of that. Do I call for specific scenes? or What?

Comment: Kind of irrelevant... but... You're*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.onclick` event for every radio button

```
 <radio onclick="myfun(url-to-image )" />
```

jQuery:

```
function myfun(var i) {
    $(#sceneoption).css("background-image", "URl(i)");
}
```